# How to assign AAD group to Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlRoleAssignments [Resolved]

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to use sqlRoleAssignments to grant an AAD user group permissions to a Cosmos DB. I've successfully setup a POC using an Azure Function connecting to Cosmos DB using a sqlRoleAssignment.

When I assign a user group which I'm part of to the same sqlRoleAssignment, and run the function locally I receive following error indicating I don't have sufficient rights.

`[2023-04-29T06:02:51.177Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: readdatabases. Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Client: Response status code does not indicate success: Forbidden (403); Substatus: 5301; ActivityId: 459dd11a-2dd1-4730-9487-adb7ccebf166; Reason: (Request blocked by Auth cosmos-account-masterclass-4661b132 : Request is blocked because principal [principalId of user in the group] does not have required RBAC permissions to perform action [Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/readMetadata] on resource [/]. Learn more: https://aka.ms/cosmos-native-rbac.`

The assignment is done through bicep and is almost identical to the assignment of the system managed identity of the function.

```
var developersGroupObjectId = '*object id of the developers group*'
var roleAssignmentDevelopersId = guid(roleDefinitionId, developersGroupObjectId, cosmosAccount.id)
resource sqlRoleAssignmentDevelopersGroup 'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlRoleAssignments@2021-04-15' = {
  parent: cosmosAccount
  name: roleAssignmentDevelopersId
  properties: {
    roleDefinitionId: sqlRoleDefinition.id
    principalId: developersGroupObjectId
    scope: cosmosAccount.id
  }
}
```

Is it correct that the role assignments aren’t inherited from the groups the user is part of?
If this is the case, are there alternative methods to manage access for users through Azure AD groups?

[UPDATE]

It turns out role assignments are inherited from the user group and thus can be used for granting permissions to groups. The issue was in the required renewal of the access token after assigning myselve to the user group as descibed in the [Limitation of using managed identities for authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/managed-identity-best-practice-recommendations#limitation-of-using-managed-identities-for-authorization).

> Given that the identity's groups and roles are claims in the access token, any authorization changes do not take effect until the token is refreshed. For a human user that's typically not a problem, because a user can acquire a new access token by logging out and in again (or waiting for the token lifetime to expire, which is 1 hour by default).

Answer (score 1):

You need the role "Cosmos DB Built-in Data Reader" and "Cosmos DB Built-in Data Contributor" created and assigned to the service principal.

Azure Cosmos DB has two built-in role definitions:

[image]

Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-setup-rbac#metadata-requests)

Comment: I've created a custom role with the required permissions. The hosted azure function, who has been assigned to this custom role, works fine. When I assign the same role to an AAD group, which I'm part of, I get the error message indicating I don't have sufficient rights. (I'm authenticated locally and the UUID in the error message is mine). I'm looking for a way to grant groups of people rights to a cosmos DB through Azure AD.